# Detecting installed MSVC redistributables programmatically

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msvcrt

is there any way to do it in C++? I'd like to do it like that:

user starts app -> app checks for installed redists -> app tells user to install redistributable X in order to use application and closes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your best bet is [MsiQueryProductState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here are two good articles:

[How to programmatically obtain the installation state of Visual Studio .NET or Visual Studio 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/884468)

[Determining if the VC Runtimes Are Installed](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Is_VC_Runtime_Installed)  (Delphi code example):

```
// API call to msi.dll to determine is a MSI installed packed has been installed.
// It does this by checking the state of the installed package.
// Anything other than a return value of INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT (5) indicates a broken or
// no installation.
function MsiQueryProductState(szProduct: String): Integer; external 'MsiQueryProductStateA@msi.dll stdcall';

// String constants to pass to the routine.
const
   // These constants check for any install of the version specific package
   // regardless the service pack or security update.  There are specific
   // constants for x86, x64 and i64 installations.
   VC2005_ANY_x86        = 'vc2005x86';
   VC2005_ANY_x64        = 'vc2005x64';
   VC2005_ANY_i64        = 'vc2005i64';
   ...
   // All available VC 2005 (version 8.0) installations.
   VC2005_x86            = '{A49F249F-0C91-497F-86DF-B2585E8E76B7}';
   VC2005_x64            = '{6E8E85E8-CE4B-4FF5-91F7-04999C9FAE6A}';
   ...
   // All available VC 2008 (version 9.0) installations.
   VC2008_x86            = '{FF66E9F6-83E7-3A3E-AF14-8DE9A809A6A4}';
   VC2008_x64            = '{350AA351-21FA-3270-8B7A-835434E766AD}';
   ...
function VCRT_IsInstalled(sPackage: String): Integer;
var
   nResult: Integer;

begin
   // Check for the existence of msi.dll.  The poor man's way of checking for the
   // installation of the Windows Installation Engine.
   If FileExists(ExpandConstant('{sys}\msi.dll')) then begin

      // Default return value of -1, which indicated no installation.  This is only 
      // necessary for the VC*_ANY_* flags as individual return values are not captured.
      Result := -1;

      // Check for the package passed ia the sPackage parameter.
      case sPackage of
         VC2005_ANY_x86:
            begin
               If (MsiQueryProductState(VC2005_x86) = 5) or
               (MsiQueryProductState(VC2005_SP1_x86) = 5) or 
               (MsiQueryProductState(VC2005_SP1_SECUP_x86) = 5) then begin
                  Result := 5;
               end;
            end;
         VC2008_ANY_x86:
            begin
               If (MsiQueryProductState(VC2008_x86) = 5) or 
               (MsiQueryProductState(VC2008_SP1_x86) = 5) or 
               (MsiQueryProductState(VC2008_SP1_SECUP_x86) = 5) then begin
                  Result := 5;
          ...
         VC2010_ANY_i64:
            begin
               If MsiQueryProductState(VC2010_i64) = 5 then begin
                  Result := 5;
               end;
            end;

         // All speific versions are checked here.  The return value is passed back
         // as the functions return value.
         else 
            begin
               Result := MsiQueryProductState(sPackage);
            end;
      end;
   end else begin

      // MSI not installed.  Pass the specific error number for it.
      Result := INSTALLSTATE_MSIABSENT;
   end;
end;
```

Here is the list of redistributable codes for MSVS 2015:

- [Distributable Code for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 RC and Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 SDK RC (Includes Utilities & BuildServer Files)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/2015-redistributables-rc-vs.aspx)